# Incorrect world-to-camera matrix with euler angles (yaw, pitch, roll)

Tags: scipy, computer-vision, coordinate-systems, coordinate-transformation, photogrammetry

I have a DJI Mavic 3M drone where I shoot images of the ground. For further processing, I need to obtain the world-to-camera transformation matrix. The drone saves the yaw, pitch and roll angles for both the drone and the gimbal. Since the camera is attached to the gimbal, I only use the euler angles of the gimbal.

However, using scipy's `Rotation` object, I obtain an incorrect rotation. The way how I checked that the rotation is incorrect is by feeding all the drone images to `OpenDroneMap` and obtain the world-to-camera rotation from the `reconstruction.json` file.

In `scipy` then I just call `Rotation.from_euler("zyx", [yaw, pitch, roll])` to obtain the `Rotation` object.

The euler angles I obtained from `OpenDroneMap` are: **z: -2.25155729 y: -0.30835846 x: -179.96534315**.
The euler angles of the gimbal that the image data shows me are: **z: 0.70 y: -89.90 x: 0.00**.

What is the usual way of constructing the world-to-camera matrix when I have the origin point of the camera in world coordinates and the yaw, pitch and roll angles?

Comment: Please provide complete code in the question so it can be copy-pasted and run to reproduce the problem.